# Android - Detect touch event on a parent which is full of children

Tags: android

Suppose I have a parent view (for example a `LinearLayout`) which accommodate some child view(for example `Button`) that occupy whole space of their parent space, What I want is I want to detect swipe event on the parent. For this purpose I choose *Touch*  event for the parent, But when I touch the parent(that is full of children) the `onTouch` handler does not trigger at all. I think this is because of its children.
Can anyone please point me out how can I achieve my purpose ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Answer (score 2):

Override the onInterceptTouchEvent() method of the parent view and let it return true.
You can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Set touchfocus of child view false. Then parent view Touch event calls.

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```